# Are HttpContext.Items shared between requests in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core

If I set something as `HttpContext.Items["Username"] = "adam";`. Is `HttpContext.Items["Username"]` going to be unique for each request or they can get overlapped between the requests?

Comment: No they shouldn't be.
HttpContext.Items

The Items collection is a good location to store data that is needed only while processing one particular request. The collection's contents are discarded after each request. The Items collection is best used as a way for components or middleware to communicate when they operate at different points in time during a request and have no direct way to pass parameters. For more information, see Working with HttpContext.Items, later in this article. (From ASP.NET Core site)

Comment: I'm not sure why but I'm seeing them persist across requests so I've abandoned the use of the items dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Are HttpContext.Items shared between requests in asp.net core?

Short Answer: **No**

To quote [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?tabs=aspnetcore2x#working-with-httpcontextitems)

> **Working with HttpContext.Items**
>
> The `HttpContext` abstraction provides
>   support for a dictionary collection of type `IDictionary<object, object>`, called `Items`. This collection is available from the start of
>   an *HttpRequest* and is discarded at the end of each request. You can
>   access it by assigning a value to a keyed entry, or by requesting the
>   value for a particular key.

Reference [Introduction to session and application state in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

So Items are discarded at the end of each request and are only relevant for the current request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I have a static property of type `IHttpContextAccessor` in a class and then try to access `IHttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items` using that static property, would it give me correct values in each request?

Comment: @user3219798 the context provided would be that of the current request. `IHttpContextAccessor` is usually registered as a singleton (static)